# expected unqualified-id before int c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, declaration

Can someone find my mistake?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void (int n, int &M[][]){
//here comes my code
}
```

when i build shows "expected unqualified-id before 'int' "

Comment: There's too many things wrong with this declaration. What are you trying to declare (using words)?

Comment: Give your function a name and make your second parameter a reasonable type

Comment: i want to put a matrix in the function

Comment: Nothing at all is not a valid name for a function.

Comment: i put the name of the function but it is still wrong

Comment: @user7367397  What does n mean in the declaration?

Comment: it was supposed to be the size of the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you mean the following

```
template <size_t N>
void process_matrix( int ( &M )[N][N] )
{
    //here comes my code
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void process_matrix(int(&m)[N][N])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++) m[i][j] = i * N + j;
    }

    for (const auto &row : m)
    {
        for (int x : row) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m1[2][2];

    process_matrix(m1);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    int m2[3][3];

    process_matrix(m2);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1
2 3

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Comment: how do i fix N value?